# SUSY, ways to boost Chargino/Neutralino production?

Tags: particle-physics, specific-reference, supersymmetry, feynman-diagrams, scattering-cross-section

Does anybody know a good reference that works out the [equations](http://www.google.com/search?q=chargino+neutralino+production+cross+section+susy+equations) for the Chargino/Neutralino production cross section in SUSY? I'm trying to understand if there are any tricks for boosting the production cross section.

So far, I have just been testing using [Prospino](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9611232) and discovered a couple patterns which seem counter-intuitive. For one, the production cross section seems to increase as I increase the masses of the squarks. This is strange because I would expect there to also be a contribution from strong production of chargino/neutralino so lower squark masses should boost the production.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you looked at section 44.8 of the [2012 review of particle physics](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2012/reviews/rpp2012-rev-cross-section-formulae.pdf) ? (I think the cross sections described there are leading order, they're given as function of Mandelstam variables and are partonic cross sections, i.e. do not take into account effects due to parton distribution functions if you are talking about a hadron collider)

Answer (score 1):

$pp$ collisions can produce neutralinos and charginos directly via electroweak production. This can occur via $s$-channel $\gamma$, $Z$ or $W$, e.g.,
$$
q\bar{q} \to Z \to \chi^0_i \chi^0_j,
$$
which is a Yukawa Z-Zino-Higgsino interaction (and is significant if $i\ne j$), or via $t$-channel squarks, which is a $q$-$\tilde{q}$-Zino interaction.

You might be able to boost these diagrams by enhancing the Higgsino or electroweakino components of the lightest neutralino and chargino, or, of course, by decreasing the masses of the supersymmetric particles.

Alternatively, $pp$ collisions can produce neutralinos and charginos via cascade decays of squarks and gluinos (QCD production). From my memory, whilst prospino calculates the production cross sections at NLO for squarks and gluinos, you must decay the particles by calculating their branching ratios with a separate program (see http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0609292).

I think, then, that you are looking only at electroweak production, rather than QCD production. Could you be clearer about the behaviour you observe? Which MSSM parameter do you increase? What is its effect on the masses and composition of the lightest neutralino or chargino?

A shot in the dark: maybe if you are increasing the scalar masses $m_0$, this results in increased $\mu$ via EWSB conditions, decreasing the Higgsino component of the lightest neutralino and chargino, and enhancing $t$-channel electroweak production?

See "Neutralino pair production at proton-proton collider" http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0003292 for a fuller discussion